# textPanel.setText(""); doesn't work or display

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea, settext

Whenever I press "clear" in my Java GUI, it never works, please help me finish this. If i replace "textPanel" with another button, it works, otherwise with "textpanel" it doesn't.

Here is a lightweight version of my code demonstrating the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private TextPanel textPanel;
    private FormPanel formpanel;

    public MainFrame(){
        super("My Frame");
        createLayout();
        createFrame();
    }

    public void createFrame(){
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);       
    }

    public void createLayout(){
        BorderLayout myLayout = new BorderLayout();     
        setLayout(myLayout);

        textPanel = new TextPanel();
        formpanel = new FormPanel();

        // adding components
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(formpanel, BorderLayout.WEST);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MainFrame();
    }

    public static class FormPanel extends JPanel {

        private JButton clear;
        private TextPanel textPanel;

        public FormPanel(){
            clear = new JButton("Clear Cart!");
            textPanel=new TextPanel();
            add(clear);

            clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aev){
                    System.out.println("Test");
                    textPanel.setText("");
                }       
            });
            createGrid();               
        }

        /* this methods simply creates the layout  */ 
        void createGrid(){
            //creating layout
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());     
            GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gc.gridy++;
            gc.weightx = .1;
            gc.weighty = .1;
            gc.gridx = 2;
            gc.gridy=5;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START; 
            gc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

            add(clear, gc);

        }
    }

    public static class TextPanel extends JPanel {
        private JTextArea textArea;

        TextPanel (){
            textArea = new JTextArea();
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        public void appendSomeText(String t){
            textArea.append(t);     
        }

        public void setText(String s){
            textArea.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I make my clear button actually clear the text Panel?

Comment: Way overkill on the code, please change this code dump to a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), nobody wants to look through all of that.

Comment: Do you get any console output when you press the button?

Comment: I get nothing, it doesn't affect the textPanel at all.

Comment: If you don't get a output "Test" then the snippet you posted there doesn't get executed

Comment: The "test" gets exectuted, once we press the clear, just not in the text panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two instances of `TextPanel`, one in `MainFrame` and the other one in `FormPanel`. `TextPanel` that is defined in `FormPanel` is actually not added to the panel, so `textPanel.setText("");` has no effect on it as it is not visible.

When the text appended with `Add To Cart!` button it actually goes through a method in `MainFrame` - `formEventOccurred()` that executes  `textPanel.appendSomeText()`. This is the other instance of `TextPanel` that is part of `MainFrame` and that is actually visible.

Looks like you need to move the duplicated logic from the main frame to the panels. Usually you should not extend `JFrame` as you are not adding any new functionality.

Comment: But when I get rid of textPanel=new TextPanel(); from  FormPanel I get an error in my textPanel.setText(""); saying java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: and when I remove it from the MainFrome, the program messes up and doesn't display any buttons, or the panel.

Comment: @user3389471 no doubt that you need to refactor and reorganize your program. As it is now, you cannot simply comment one line and make it work. Cleanup the `MainFrame`, it is only a top level container. It should contain your panels but not actions logic. Look into [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) so you can isolate and reuse functionality in you panels and toolbar.

Comment: @NickRippe I appreciate your edit, I rolled it back because I think OP needs to step back for a moment and rethink the design of this program. The program is only at a rough draft stage but already has many problems. A quick hack-through solution will only make more mess.

Comment: @Aqua I guess that's fair enough - it's your answer.  Personally I feel like if I can help make the answer more clear it can't be a bad thing.  My philosophy is give them the answer they're looking for and point out if there's a better way then hope it takes.  But I accept that there's other viewpoints out there.  Thanks for addressing it!

Comment: @Aqua Thanks guys,I understand My code is a mess, but I am still a beginner, I have a lot more things to learn. I honestly am very lost at the moment, and don't understand what I should do next.

Comment: @user3389471 remove `TextPanel` from `MainFrame`. Add `textPanel` in `FormPanel.createGrid()` just like the rest of component in `FormPanel`. Then, move the logic of `appendSomeText` into `FormPanel` as well. Or better, encapsulate it in separate actions. Then both `FormPanel` and `Toolbar` can use these actions. Was it a requirement to use `StringListener` and `FormListener` approach ?

Comment: It was.. sadly, but I fixed it!I made it so I could call the `textpanel`  in `formpanel` by creating a method and using `this.textPanel = textPanel;`. I created a method in `TextPanel` that would `setText` to blank. Then in My mainframe I simply put `formpanel.setCart(textPanel);`